# Test device using startApp

Tags: android, ads, startapp

I am testing startApp for the first time and walking through the documentation I didn't find any method to add a test device like what I usually do using admob . 
I am developing for android .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to add a test device when using StartApp.

Comment: What happens if someone clicks their own ads ?!

Comment: It's only worth pennies, so either startapp doesn't care or they can ban based on IP Address